# Changing A Value in Mulithread Programming

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, race-condition

I have a project about marriage operations. In this program, a thread called registrar uses marriage function. In this marriage operations, we have brides and grooms. Marriage function does decrease bride count and groom count one by one. But i have a problem while i want to decrease these count.

> ## MAIN.c

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include "bride.h"
#include "groom.h"

pthread_t groomThread;
pthread_t brideThread;
sem_t registrarSemaphore;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

int *groomCount = 14;
int *brideCount = 20;
int *availableRegistrar;

void createBride(int *brideCount) {
    pthread_create(&brideThread, NULL, &increaseBrideCount, (void *) brideCount);
}

void createGroom(int *groomCount) {
    pthread_create(&groomThread, NULL, &increaseGroomCount, (void *) groomCount);
}

void deleteGroom(int *groomCount) {
    pthread_create(&groomThread, NULL, &decreaseGroomCount, (void *) groomCount);
}

void deleteBride(int *brideCount) {
    pthread_create(&brideThread, NULL, &decreaseBrideCount, (void *) brideCount);
}


void marriage() {
    sem_init(&registrarSemaphore, 0, 2);

    while (1) {
        sem_getvalue(&registrarSemaphore, &availableRegistrar);

        printf("\nAvailable Registrar Number = %d\n", availableRegistrar);

        printf("bride %d\n", brideCount);
        printf("groom %d\n", groomCount);

        if (brideCount > 0 && groomCount > 0) {
            sem_wait(&registrarSemaphore);
            sem_getvalue(&registrarSemaphore, &availableRegistrar);
            printf("Available Registrar %d \n", availableRegistrar);

            printf("Marriage Bride %d and Groom %d \n", brideCount, groomCount);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            deleteBride(brideCount);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            //pthread_join(brideThread, &brideCount);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            deleteGroom(groomCount);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            //pthread_join(groomThread, &groomCount);
            printf("Exiting critical region...\n\n");
            /* END CRITICAL REGION */
            sem_post(&registrarSemaphore);
        }


        int random = rand() % 100;
        if (random % 7 > 4) {
            printf("Bride Created\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            createBride(brideCount);
            //pthread_join(brideThread, &brideCount);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        }

        if (random % 7 < 2) {
            printf("Groom Created\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            createGroom(groomCount);
            //pthread_join(groomThread, &groomCount);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }

        pthread_join(brideThread, &brideCount);
        pthread_join(groomThread, &groomCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++);
        printf("------------------------------");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    marriage();
}
```

In pthread_create part, there are some functions as you can see. It defined in .h part. For example in bride.h, there are 2 functions about bride.

> ## BRIDE.H

```
#ifndef BRIDE_H
#define BRIDE_H

void* increaseBrideCount(void * bride);
void* decreaseBrideCount(void * bride);

#endif
```

> ## BRIDE.C

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "bride.h"


void* increaseBrideCount(void *bride){
    int brideCount = (int)bride;
    brideCount++;
    pthread_exit(brideCount);
}

void* decreaseBrideCount(void* bride){
    int brideCount = (int)bride;
    brideCount--;
    pthread_exit(brideCount);
}
```

While im creating new bride,i cant send the new value of bride to the function. For example :

I have 20 brides and 14 grooms at first. 
I have 2 available registrar

Marraige does.

Bride count = 19, groom count = 13

Then, i want to create new bride.

It count goes to = 1 :( Im trying to make it 20 again.

If you can help, i would be very happy. Thank you

Comment: Why do you create a new thread and immediately join it? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think that pthread_join function returns the value of the thread. In ptread_create function goes there and does its job than returns it(pthread_exit).I can read phtread_exit with pthread_join, am i wrong :(

Comment: But when one thread joins another, the former waits for the latter to complete.  If the former is not going to perform any work at all in parallel with the latter, then it might as well have performed the latter thread's work directly.

Comment: It waits until the thread finishes, so it's pointless to create a thread and then wait for it immediately, it would be better to call the function directly.

Comment: But i have to use threads. I can send the functions by using .h libraries but how can i do that by using threads

Comment: So track the thread IDs as you create the threads, and join all of them later, some time after creating the last of them.

Comment: Wow, it means i have to use a thread array? I will try it, thank you

Comment: Or if possible, change *how* you use threads.  Threads have non-trivial overhead, so they are not well suited for microtasks such as you are making yours perform.  You might, for instance, create a single thread that generates brides and a single one that generates grooms, plus one other to perform marriages (or use the main thread for the last).

Answer (score 2):

Semaphores are used to make sure only one of the threads that might make a particular change does so at a time.  The things being changed in this case are the bride and groom counts, so you need to "protect" them using semaphores.  You even seem to have created semaphores for this purpose (`brideSemaphore` and `groomSemaphore`); you just need to use them.

By the way: if you use a semaphore only in a single thread, you're wasting your time (as seems to be the case w/ your `registrarSemaphore`) in `marriage()`).  Either it needs to be used elsewhere as well, or not at all.

Comment: It's not just about ordering.  Semaphores, when used appropriately, also ensure that each thread sees the effects of the others' writes.  The fact that threads might *not* see each others' writes without some form of synchronization is one of the more common things that cause people trouble with threads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use registrar semaphore because i have 2 registrars in this case. One of it does marriable, registrarCount--;  But i think that there is a problem while im using threads :( I know that, one thread can execute one function. Am i wrong? Im opening two threads for increase and decrease for that purpose :) Our teachers said that bride and grooms must be a thread and im trying to do these operations by using threads

Comment: Mutex are also a (maybe easier) possibilty.

Comment: I changed binary semaphores to mutex as you said. But my problem seems in the thread part i guess